# Proof of homotopy lifting lemma.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, intuition, covering-spaces, visualization

I am a graduate student.In this semester we have a topology course with a basic introduction to fundamental groups and covering spaces.While studying covering spaces,I encountered the following theorem which is called the *homotopy-lifting lemma*.It is as follows:

> Let $F:I\times I\to X$ be a continuous map such that $F(0,t)=F(1,t)=x_0$ for $t\in [0,1]$.Then there is a unique continuous map $\tilde F:I\times I\to \tilde X$ such that $p\circ \tilde F=F$ and $\tilde F(0,t)=\tilde x_0,t\in [0,1]$.

Where $p:\tilde X\to X$ is a covering map and $I=[0,1]$ and $\tilde x_0\in p^{-1}(x_0)$.

I want a proof of this theorem and also some intuition of what is going on.Can someone help me?

Comment: This is in just about any intro book in algebraic topology/homotopy theory:  it is standard.  Do you have any or have access to any?

Comment: @Randall I have access to Munkres but there the statement is a bit different.Can you tell me what the statement actually means?

Comment: @Randall Can you give me a concrete example of homotopy lifting?

Comment: The best example comes when you want to associate the size of $\pi_1(X)$ with the size of the fiber when $\tilde{X}$ is simply connected.  For this, you have to show that a homotopy of loops in $X$ lifts a certain way to a homotopy of paths (not loops!) in $\tilde{X}$, showing that the endpoints of the lift must live in the fiber.  This is what homotopy lifting gets you.

Comment: Your question is missing some important [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) regarding your own attempts. For example, you have mentioned the definition of homotopy lifting in Munkres, but have you attempted to understand how that definition compares with the definition in your post? Have you attempted to work through theorems/examples of homotopy lifting in Munkres to get any intuition? Where did you get stuck on these attempts? Asking specific questions along these lines would greatly improve your post.